# Count If MySql With Distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

please help me for this query, i have this data

```
customeid | param
1001      |  A
1001      |  B
1001      |  C
1002      |  B
1002      |  A
1003      |  A
1003      |  B
1004      |  A
```

i need to distinct customeid, i use this query but the result not correct

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(param not in ('A'),1,0))
FROM
  table
```

the output result

```
count   
  3 (from customeid 1001,1002,1003)
```

how to distinct customeid with if param not in A and ican't add where query

Comment: An output table would help

Comment: expected output is 3?

Comment: yes i want to count customeid distinct where param != A but i can't use where query, because this is only part of my select query.

Comment: count must be 3 for your table if i am right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `count` `if` with `distinct`  to judge that there is no problem, but there are issues, If the condition is met You need to return `customeid`, otherwise you need to return `null`

You can follow this query.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(param not in ('A'),customeid,NULL))
FROM
  table
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed1577/4)

**NOTE**

`COUNT` won't accumulate when that value is `null`

Comment: No problem :),Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

use `case when` and aggregate function `group by`

```
 select customeid,count(*) as Count
 from (    
    select (case when param!='A' then customeid else end) as customeid    from your_table
) T group by customeid
```

Comment: @Denny R.z does it help

Answer (score 0):

```
select customeid,count(customeid)
from table
where param <>'A'
group by customeid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT COSTUMEID, COUNT(DISTINCT (PARAM))
FROM TABLE 
WHERE PARAM NOT IN (('A'),1,0) 
GROUP BY COSTUMEID
```